# How to run Python and Jupyter in AWS EC2 + Ubuntu when using Windows+puTTY?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, window, jupyter, putty

I just started trying AWS EC2 free tier. I use Windows 10 + puTTY to connect ubuntu in ec2. So far, where I have got is:

[image]

You can see that I already can use putty to link to Ubuntu. And python and Jupyter have been already installed. But, I do not know how to use Jupyter for Python coding.

PS.I also tried the methods presented in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/setup-jupyter-configure-client-windows.html, but I do not know how to continue.

So, how can I use Jupyter and Python in EC2 when using puTTP to link to AWS?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for opening this query. Apologies for the delayed response.
We investigated the above query and looks like the port setup for using Jupyter notebook on your instance has not been done correctly. We would recommend following [steps from the guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/setup-jupyter.html).

Essentially, your ec2 instance should allow for opening a port and setting up a server. The logs pasted above indicated that no server was up and this might have been because the ec2 instance wasn't configured with the correct configuration. Please ensure that you setup a `Custom TCP Rule` as mentioned above while launching your instance and then try the above steps again.

Please feel free to comment and let us know if this doesn't solve your issue.